# Entering a building with Liquidtight Flexible Non-Metallic PVC Conduit with a 90 degree fitting

Tags: conduit

Do I have to transition to hard PVC 90 with a cover to enter the building - https://www.homedepot.com/p/Carlon-3-4-in-Gray-Schedule-40-and-80-PVC-Type-LB-Conduit-Body-E986E-CTN/100404084?  Or can I run the flex straight through the wall & into the panel, seal to siding/exterior EPS with silicone?  I have to run a 3/4" (12v controls) and 1-1/4" (220v) line for a generator about 20' away.  Or should I do it in 100% hard PVC pipe with expansion couplers on each end - expensive?

Comment: How are you making the transition from the buried conduit to the LFNC?

Comment: With LFNC, can I run it as one piece with no joints or does code require a 90 degree fitting?  Does code require a expansion coupler or is that only when using solid pipe?

Comment: I can't answer that question unless I know what's going on with the buried run (due to pull point/consecutive bend limits)

Comment: Or did you bury LFNC instead of rigid conduit?

Comment: Let me put it this way: why are you using LFNC for the stub-up here?

Comment: So I can't run LFNC underground?  1 piece from the side of the generator into the house.

Comment: Photo may help - https://photos.app.goo.gl/gPyUHLfetL9W74c86

Comment: Or can I use 1 or 2 PVC Junction box to make the 90 degree into the house for both lines without a expansion coupler?  I would probable replace the 1/2 ground box with this.

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Carlon-4-in-x-4-in-x-2-in-PVC-Junction-Box-Gray-E989NNJ-CAR/100404097

Comment: I take it the LFNC in question exits directly out the bottom of the generator's wiring compartment, with no 90deg fitting on the generator end?